# proving that $f_n$ doesn't uniformly converge

Tags: calculus, inequality, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that $$fn(x)=(nx)/(1+n^2x^4)$$ doesn't uniformly converge in **[0,1]**
For that I'm looking for K a real positive fixed number, m,n $\in \mathbb{N}$ which achieve the following inequality:

$$|nx/(1+n^2x^4) - mx/(1+m^2x^4)| \ge K. $$

**Why I'm doing this?
well because we learnt that fn(x) uniformly converge when for every epsilon > 0 there is N a natural number S.t for every m,n > N and every x in my field the following is true:
|fn(x)-fm(x)| <= epsilon**

So I wasn't successful solving this and uploaded the following question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3685851

> Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I'm looking for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ which
>   achives the following:
>
> Note: $m$ is expected to be related to $n$. For example $m=2n$....
>
> $$|n/(1+n^2) - m/(1+m^2)| \ge K. $$    $K > 0$, $K$: constant. An
>   Example: $K = 0.5$

and it seems that people are struggling with it, am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $x:=\frac1{\sqrt n}$ check that
$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^4}=\frac{\sqrt n}2$$
and
$$f_{2n}(x)=\frac{2nx}{1+4n^2x^4}=\frac{2\sqrt n}5$$
so that
$$
\left|f_n(x)-f_{2n}(x)\right| =\frac{\sqrt n}{10}
$$
So given $N\ge1$ you can take $n=N$, $m=2N$, $x=\frac1{\sqrt N}$ to satisfy your Cauchy criterion. For the value of $K$ you can take $K=\frac{1}{10}$.

The question you uploaded previously received no answer because you didn't translate your Cauchy criterion correctly: you forced $x=1$, which doesn't  yield any $m, n$ that satisfy.

Comment: Please Note that according to the negation of Cauchy crteria I can't choose N, it should be for every N (a natural number)

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: what about N=0 (0 is normal number)

Comment: Normally you don't worry about small values of $N$ -- what matters is the large $N$. But for the special case $N=0$ you can take $n=1$, $m=2$, and $x=1$

Comment: last questions, I heard a lot "you don't worry about small values of " but why? the crteria says "For every N" and not for large N values. Plus how did you really think about this solution, for example I took x=1 because it seems an easy number and would never think that it will cause problems...

Comment: The reason you don't worry about small $N$: If someone hands you a small $N$, you convert it to a large $N_1$ that you know how to handle. The $m$ and $n$ (and $x$) that work for your large $N_1$ will also work for your small $N$.

Comment: The reason you don't guess $x$ to be an easy number: Typically the $x$ that works will need to depend on $N$. The is true for when the criterion is "for every $N$ ... there exists $x$..."

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to observe that
for $n>0$

$$\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|f_n(x)-0|\ge $$

$$f_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}|f_n(x)-0|=+\infty$$
The convergence is not uniform.

Comment: But what if I consider 0 to be a natural number? and why you took sup ?

Comment: @clark979m We are interested by the limit, so $n$ is assumed to be great.

Comment: ok but could you change the sup method to my own? I am interested in it

Comment: @clark979m You tried the negation of  Cauchy crteria. it is not obvious.

Comment: yes I tried that, so there is no solution using the negation of Cauchy crteria?